# Each word in a new div

Tags: javascript

I want the normal behavior of the cursor as in a textarea, try on chrome navigator please.

I'm using a `contenteditable` but it should work as if it were a textarea, 
every word must be in a span that is very necessary, I do not want to work with plain text

For each space, each written word must become a div or span, 
and the cursor should behave normally

example:

```
        "hello word" for the space the result will is 
         <div>hello</div>


         imagine that the second space is after the word "word", 
         for the second space the result will is 
         <div>hello</div><div>word</div>

        and written spacebar before the caracter 'r'
        the result will is <div>hello</div><div>wo</div><div>rd</div>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
      var parent = document.getElementById("test");
      var range = document.createRange();
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var number = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id;

      convertirEnSpans();
      agregarIds();
      //parent.childNodes[parseInt(number) + 1] el nodo siguiente
      //el cursor debe situarse en el inicio del nodo siguiente
      if (parent.childNodes[parseInt(number) + 1] !== undefined) { //comprobamos que exista el nodo siguiente
        var element = parent.childNodes[parseInt(number) + 1];
        range.setStart(element, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        element.focus();
      }
    }
  });

  function convertirEnSpans() {
    let text = document.getElementById('test');
    let spans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
    if (spans.length > 0) {
      text = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        text += spans[i].innerHTML + ' ';
      }
      text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    } else {
      text = text.innerHTML;
    }

    var wordsWithSpan = text.split(' ').map(function(c) {
      return '<span class="word">' + c + '</span>';
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = wordsWithSpan;
  }

  function agregarIds() { //agregamos ids para saber en que nodo esta en cursor
    text = document.getElementById('test');
    let nodeSpans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeSpans.length; i++) {
      nodeSpans[i].id = i;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">
</div>
```

I can not get the cursor to behave normally, the cursor jumps to all parts, how to fix it?

I'm only interested in working with spacebar, 
do not try it with the enter key

Update with answer of @DurgeshAhire
but errors still exist when writing in the middle of a word

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
      var parent = document.getElementById("test");
      var range = document.createRange();
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var number = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id;

      convertirEnSpans();
      agregarIds();

      //parent.childNodes[parseInt(number) + 1] el nodo siguiente
      //el cursor debe situarse en el inicio del nodo siguiente
      if (parent.childNodes[parseInt(number) + 2] !== undefined) { //comprobamos que exista el nodo siguiente
        var element = parent.childNodes[parseInt(number) + 1];
        range.setStart(element, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        element.focus();
      } else {
        setEndOfContenteditable(parent);
      }
    }
  });


  function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
    var range, selection;
    if (document.createRange) { //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
      range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
      range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
      range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
      selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
      selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
      selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
    } else if (document.selection) //IE 8 and lower
    {
      range = document.body.createTextRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
      range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
      range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
      range.select(); //Select the range (make it the visible selection
    }
  }



  function convertirEnSpans() {
    let text = document.getElementById('test');
    let spans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
    if (spans.length > 0) {
      text = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        text += spans[i].innerHTML + ' ';
      }
      text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    } else {
      text = text.innerHTML;
    }

    var wordsWithSpan = text.split(' ').map(function(c) {
      return '<span class="word">' + c + '</span>';
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = wordsWithSpan;
  }

  function agregarIds() { //agregamos ids para saber en que nodo esta en cursor
    text = document.getElementById('test');
    let nodeSpans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeSpans.length; i++) {
      nodeSpans[i].id = i;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: on pressing enter, i see there comes new text box but when i start to write something, then it goes back to upper text box, is this the expected behaviour. Do you just need to fix the cursor jumping problem

Comment: @Kowsalya 
I'm only interested in working with spacebar

Comment: @x-rw What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @hev1 
the cursor should behave normally, as if it were a textArea working with plain text

Comment: @hev1 
but in my example the cursor goes crazy, the answer of Durgesh Ahire 
solves but not all cases (write in the middle of a word the cursor should not jump at the end if not the next word)

Comment: @x-rw-you just want to achieve it using javascript or jquey is also fine?

Comment: @NullPointer 
with jquery or javascript is fine

Comment: @x-rw- can you check my answer if it work for you.I think you do not need to maintain too much code for this(i.e. you have written)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This code lets you type in the middle of words without messing up the caret position! You can even paste text into the div, and it will update immediately! Multiple spaces in a row are also supported! Selecting and deleting a range of characters (cutting in through words) works too!**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("test");
    var range = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var number = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id;

    let pos = getCaret();

    convertirEnSpans();
    agregarIds();

    setCaret(pos);
  });

  function getCaret() {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(test);
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      return preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  }

  function setCaret(offset) {
    let nodeSpans = test.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var temp = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeSpans.length; i++) {
      let len = (nodeSpans[i].innerText || nodeSpans[i].textContent).length;
      if (temp + len >= offset) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(nodeSpans[i].childNodes[0], offset - temp);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        break;
      }
      else {
        temp += len;
      }
    }
  }

  function convertirEnSpans() {
    let text = test.innerText || test.textContent;
    var wordsWithSpan = text.split(/\s/ugmi).map(function(c) {
      if (c.length > 0) return `<span class="word">${c}</span>`;
      else return c;
    }).join('<span>&nbsp;</span>'); // non-breaking space
    test.innerHTML = wordsWithSpan;
  }

  function agregarIds() { // agregamos ids para saber en que nodo esta en cursor
    let nodeSpans = test.getElementsByClassName('word');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeSpans.length; i++) {
      nodeSpans[i].id = "word" + i; // ids are not allowed to start with a digit
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">
</div>
```

**The black borders around words is there so you can easily see the elements.**

Comment: there are still flaws when you write several words in the middle of a word

Comment: this answer is nice, 
I think it does not break in any case, it's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: what it is variable test

Comment: @x-rw Element ids are also global variables. Instead of doing `document.getElementById('test')`, you can just use the variable `test` directly. `preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(test);` sets the range to select all the nodes in the contenteditable div.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a contenteditable but it should work as if it were a textarea

I think you do not required to maintain too much off code that you have written.

**Idea is just replace the `div` with `textarea` on the fly and after getting the input from *user* replace it with `div`**

You can refer the code snippet below:

```js
function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = $(this).text();
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus(); //sets focus to element
      var val = editableText.val(); //store the value of the element
      editableText.val(""); //clear the value of the element
     editableText.val(val);  //set that value back.  
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
    var html = $(this).val();
     var wordsWithSpan = html.split(' ').map(function(c) {
      return '<span class="word">' + c + '</span>';
    }).join(' ');
    
    var viewableText = $("<div>");
    viewableText.html(wordsWithSpan);
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
    // setup the click event for this new div
    viewableText.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(divClicked);
});
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 2px;
}



div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px;
  width:400px;
}



textarea {
     border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word" contenteditable="true"></diV>
```

Comment: I think it does not fail, the cursor behaves in a normal way

Comment: @x-rw - I updated my answer with jQuery code snippet and also optimized the code.This is a working case.Thanks

Comment: must become divs for each spacebar, I think the previous code was perfect

Comment: @x-rw-I updated.Now on every spacebar it will become as div again

Comment: but the cursor is lost, the cursor should behave normally as if it were in a normal textArea, the writing should be fluent

Comment: I am Stil not getting what you want to achieve.I can rollback to my previous code but please clarify the things.1.when you click on div it should normally work as textarea. 2. if i put the space in text area what should happen? I am expecting it should be normal function as textarea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/175992/discussion-between-x-rw-and-nullpointer).

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome. When I click on the div, the textarea pops up and stays there.

Comment: @sag- I crossed checked it is working correcly also checked with F12 that it changed div to text-area and text-area to div correctly.  I am wonder for your downvote

Answer (score -1):

Please Check Updated Code and Let me know

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 32) {
          var parent = document.getElementById("test");
          var range = document.createRange();
          var selection = window.getSelection();
          var number = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id;

          convertirEnSpans();
          agregarIds();
          
          
          setEndOfContenteditable(parent);

         
        }
      });

  function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
         var range,selection;
         if(document.createRange) { //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
            range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
            range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
            range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
            selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
            selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
            selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
          }
          else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
          { 
             range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
             range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
             range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
             range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
        }
     }

      function convertirEnSpans() {
        let text = document.getElementById('test');
        let spans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
        if (spans.length > 0) {
          text = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            text += spans[i].innerHTML + ' ';
          }
          text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        } else {
          text = text.innerHTML;
        }

        var wordsWithSpan = text.split(' ').map(function(c) {
          return '<span class="word">' + c + '</span>';
        }).join('');

        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = wordsWithSpan;
      }

      function agregarIds() { //agregamos ids para saber en que nodo esta en cursor
        text = document.getElementById('test');
        let nodeSpans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
        for (var i = 0; i < nodeSpans.length; i++) {
          nodeSpans[i].id = i;
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: @x-rw Please Check

Comment: it fails when it is written in the middle of a word

Comment: ohkkk i will check

Comment: Typing in the middle of words is broken.